# SSL Certificate for Web Service in the Cloud

Tags: amazon-ec2, https, ssl-certificate

I have a Web Service hosted on the amazon cloud using their EC2 technology. The domain to that service is "amazonaws.com". When I create a CSR what do I add to the "Common Name" field?

In the end I like to have a certificate which doesn't throw any errors or warnings like "Server's certificate does not match the URL", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only buy an SSL certificate for a domain name under your control. You will have to get your own domain name, or at least your own subdomain, otherwise you can't buy a certificate.

The Common Name field should be the full domain name for your web service (including subdomain).

Comment: OK, so when I use my domain as the common name I get Name Mismatch warning when I try to access the Web Service. That's because the service runs on amazonaws.com and not on my domain. How do I solve this?

Comment: You have to run the service on your domain. Ask the system administrator how to do that.